# Sending alert message if user not logged in?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

IN my application i use MFMailComposeViewController class to send mail and i know in the case of sending mail through ipod is sucessfully when one  account is already open in that but in my application I want to a message which alert the application to open ur account.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]`. If this method returns NO, display the alert.